# Why am I unable to connect to openfire server from another computer?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, portforwarding

I have a problem connecting to `openfire`. Following is the snapshot that shows the server properties.

[image]

I have my server running and i try to connect to the server *(running on my pc)* from another pc with the following addresses :

```
blab:5222
127.0.0.1:5222
```

but the browser says *This webpage is not available* . What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: ping only pings a host, not a host+port.  Can you first give the ip-addresses of both computers (using ipconfig (windows) or ifconfig (linux)). Both will probably be 192.168.*.*

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 always points to the address of the computer you call it on (in this case your other pc). You need to find the local IP of the server computer. If your server and other pc are on the same LAN network, go to start > run > cmd and type in ipconfig on your SERVER pc. The IP you want is probably 192.168.1.xxx. Use this on your other pc to connect to your server.

You will also need to add openfire to your firewall exceptions on the server PC. You can do this through windows firewall. [Guide here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/542-windows-firewall-add-remove-exception.html)

If the server pc and this other pc are NOT on the same lan, you will need to port forward your router, which means that incoming connections on port 5522 will point to your server pcs 192.168.1.xxx local IP. After you have done this Google "whats my ip" to get your EXTERNAL ip address. [Or click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=whats%20my%20ip&oq=whats%20my%20ip&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0j5j0j69i62l2.1350j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Still following along? This external address will point to your ROUTER, which will then FORWARD to the local address of the SERVER. Use this external address to connect from your other computer. [Guide on port forwarding for your specific router here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm)

Also, a web browser defaults to port 80 or 127.0.0.1:80, so you won't be able to see the openfire service from a web browser.

Comment: As I ping `127.0.0.1:5222` from my own computer, I get this `Ping request could not find host 127.0.0.1:5222. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: and why can't I just use `blab:5222` from another pc ?

Comment: `blab` is the name of the server.Do you see the red mark in the image I uploaded ?

Comment: Doing it with a space gives `Bad parameter 5222.`

Comment: I can connect to all other ports except the port number `5222`. Why is that ? I am trying `https://192.168.177.1:5222` but cannot connect

Comment: okay I upvoted your answer. Now could you tell me the possible reason for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. Check your firewall. For checking stop your firewall for temporarily
2. Check your browser setting.
3. Check using ping that it works to your 127.0.0.1:5222

Comment: As I ping `127.0.0.1:5222` from my own computer, I get this `Ping request could not find host 127.0.0.1:5222. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: Check your firewall. For test put off the all firewall and try.